# azure-active-directory Generation of AAD Service Principal Keys

Tags: service, key, azure-active-directory, fips, principal

I would like to know how we generate AAD Service Principal Keys, specifically whether the algorithm used to generate the key is FIPS approved/accredited?

Comment: Welcome to [so], David Hoyle! Please try to post a [mcve] and see [ask] and the [help] for more information.

Comment: Do you mean to  generate the key certificate? You can have a try to use `New-AzureADServicePrincipalKeyCredential`